# Splitting complex builds in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

Up until now I have always created large builds, e.g. "checkin build" which simply assures that the code compiles and all tests are fine, jira and so forth (also reports like coverage, checkstyle etc.).
The I have another large build, "nightly", which does the same as above but also maven site, javadoc - that is, tasks which run for a longer time - that is, does a new checkout and builds everything again (ever night if changes in source control was registered).

Now I would like to do a "build for production", which more or less should do the same as "nightly", with the extension that it should tag and produce an artifact ready for deployment, bump version and so forth. Unfortunately I don't always have the time to wait for maven site etc to be produced, but I still need them for documentation purposes. I've been looking at build pipelines and inheritance plugin, but I don't know what is pro/cons with these - I'm missing a "best practice" here.

If I could have it my way I would like a build like "check build", then a new job does tagging and release of new version (e.g. release plugin), then a new job starts the "reporting" stuff and finally a job which creates maven sites etc., but I would only like to do one checkout. All these builds should then be triggered by the previous one which was build successfully. I have then been looking at "copy workspace", but this feels like the wrong way to do this.

Any input, ideas, experience etc. is much appreciated.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Re *"[...] "copy workspace", but this feels like the wrong way to do this."*

Looks like the [Shared workspace plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shared+workspace+plugin) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'll have a look, the "Build flow" plugin which Kalpesh linked to could also be a viable solution.

Comment: Shared workspace doesn't work for me, since changes can be made to the work space after the initial build... This has some unforeseen side effects.